# Trying to retrieve sra data using sra explorer

Tags: geo

I am trying to use the [SRA explorer](https://sra-explorer.info/) tool to download data from ENA. Whatever geo accession number I give it however, it will return no results. It only seems to return results for the suggestions it already has. I tried for example searching for [GSE111797](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE111797) by typing it in the search tool but didn't get anything.

Comment: It would be helpful to describe the question in more detail, like what you did more specifically. Also, since you are using a third-party tool, it might be easier to reach out to the developers themselves.

Comment: Try the corresponding SRP accession (SRP135519). It seems to work for me now.

Comment: @vkkodali yup that did it